# SyntaxError: non-keyword xlwings

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwings

While trying to run the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import SortOrder
from xlwings.constants import SortOrientation

def xlwingstest():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.app.screen_updating = 'False'

    xw.Range('A3:B8501').api.Sort(Key1=wb.Sheets('Sheet1').xw.Range('A3'), SortOrder.xlDescending, 
             SortOrientation.xlSortColumns)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "xlwings_sort_data1.py", line 16
>
> ```
> xw.Range('A3:B8501').api.Sort(Key1=wb.Sheets('Sheet1').xw.Range('A3'),
>                                SortOrder.xlDescending,
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Do you know what keyword and non-keyword arguments are? As the error says, you can't put the former after the latter.

Comment: I do not know what keyword and non-keyword arguments are, but I do know after looking at @Luca's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a keyword arg eg. `Key1=` before a non-keyword arg. From the [excel documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx), you can find the `Range.Sort` method arguments. I think you want to do :

```
xw.Range('A3:B8501').api.Sort(Key1=wb.Sheets('Sheet1').xw.Range('A3'),
 Order1=SortOrder.xlDescending,
 Orientation=SortOrientation.xlSortColumns)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it out and got the following error:
`File "c:\users\xlwings_sort_data1.py", line 16, in xlwingstest
    xw.Range('A3:B8501').api.Sort(Key1=wb.Sheets('Sheet1').xw.Range('A3'),

AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'Sheets'`